# gotonext record in a dropdownlist

Tags: vba, ms-access

i have a combobox with numbers.

I select the first and push a button then there will be added two specific records in the continuous form.

now i want to make this more advanced so that if I push the button will add another two records in the continuous form. but based on the next record into the combobox.

```
Private Sub Doublestart_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = Recordset

rs.AddNew
Me.Trail = Me.Traildoulestart
Me.RallyKlasID = 101
RallyKlasnaam.value = RallyKlasID.Column(1)
RallyKlasgroep.value = RallyKlasID.Column(2)
Me.Handler.value = Forms!FormClassEnteryRally.Form.ExhibitorRally

rs.AddNew
Me.Trail = Me.Traildoulestart
Me.RallyKlasID = 104
RallyKlasnaam.value = RallyKlasID.Column(1)
RallyKlasgroep.value = RallyKlasID.Column(2)
Me.Handler.value = Forms!FormClassEnteryRally.Form.ExhibitorRally


End Sub
```

```
Private Sub MoveDown_Click()
ComboName.SetFocus
If ComboName.ListIndex <> ComboName.ListCount - 1 Then
        ComboName.ListIndex = ComboName.ListIndex + 1
      Else
        ComboName.ListIndex = 0
      End If
End Sub
```

this works :)

try to find a code to gotorecord in dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

Increment combobox ItemData index with combobox's own ListIndex returned by current item to move to next item and populate combobox Value.

```
With Me.comboboxName
If .ListIndex <> .ListCount - 1 Then .Value = .ItemData(.ListIndex + 1)
End With
```

Comment: hi, I don't want to populate my combobox. but select item and fill a continues form with some other code. and than in a loop trough all items in the combobox.

Comment: Populating combobox allows to set focus on list item and then code can refer to each column index to pull other info. You said with button click you want to 'gotorecord in dropdown list' - my suggestion should accomplish that. Works for me. If you want to loop through all items and create 2 records for each non-stop in one button click, that is another issue. Please clarify.